# Read a JSON value from request.body in Scala & Play Framework

Tags: angularjs, json, scala, playframework

I am sending a JSON data from my angular form into a Play Framework Controller. The Controller receives the messages and when I console print it, it looks like the following:

```
{"username":"{   \"tID\": 123,   \"cID\": \"TEST\",   \"version\": 1}"}
```

What I am doing so far is: [Note: I am using `play.api.libs.json`]

```
def sendMessage = Action(parse.json) {
  request =>
  val message: JsValue = request.body
  val cID = (message \ "cID").get
}
```

However I am getting an error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get`
 because its not able to retrieve the cID from the JSON string? How do I get the value for cID without the escape character `\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of "username" is encoded `Json String`, because you should decode `Json String`

Try this.

```
def sendMessage = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  val message: JsValue = request.body
  val userNameJsonStr = (message \ "username").as[String]
  val value = Json.parse(userNameJsonStr)
  val cID = (value \ "cID")
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I think Json.parse expects a String whereas `userNameJsonStr ` is already a JsValue. The IDE complains saying `Cannot resolve reference parse with such signature`

Comment: @summerNight Sorry, commend Fixed